# graphql 400 bad request - Must provide an operation

Tags: graphql, postman

I am trying to hit a `GraphQL` query in `Postman` but it is giving 400 bad request error.

Query is:

```
type Query {
    school(id: ID, schoolCode: String): School 
}

type School {
    optionalSubjects: [String!]
    code: ID!
    defaultSubjects: String!
    defaultExams: String!
}
```

What am I missing here? I am new to GraphQL so I am not getting the cause of this error. Do I need to provide values on the right side of Postman under `GRAPHQL VARIABLES` section?

1. [400 bad request in graphql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755448/400-bad-request-in-graphql)
2. [React Apollo GraphQL Mutation returns 400 (bad request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57930636/react-apollo-graphql-mutation-returns-400-bad-request)
3. [Graphql POST call gives 400 bad request error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72598941/graphql-post-call-gives-400-bad-request-error)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the error. It says

> **Must provide an operation**

what you're doing is executing the type definition. That's like executing a function interface definition rather than the function itself in typescript.
As an example, I have a type definition like

```
const Comment = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Comment",
  fields: {
    id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
    content: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    email: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    createdAt: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
      resolve: (source) => source.createdAt.toISOString(),
    },
    postId: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
  },
});
```

followed by this query

```
 commentMainList: {
      type: new GraphQLList(new GraphQLNonNull(Comment)),
      resolve: async (source, args, { pgApi }) => {
        return pgApi.commentMainList();
      },
    },
```

and then in postman I can do

```
{
    commentMainList{
        id
        postId
        email
        content
        createdAt

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean this POST call cannot be completed without scripting? I can't run this test in POSTMAN alone?

Comment: @paul No. You have to provide  postman with an operation to perform. As of now, you haven't.

Comment: Understood! but I am not getting the syntax. I mean how to run Query type. Would it be like this?`query Query {
    school {
            id:"23", 
            schoolCode:"management21"
    }
}`

Comment: @paul

`query {
school(id: 23, schoolCode: "management21"){
**whatever you want to return here**
   }
}
`

Comment: It seems that being a QA. I only have to test the `Query` and `School` types. These Schemas are already created and I don't have to create them in Postman. Right?

Comment: @paul You just have to test the query. the School schema is what the query will return. Each item in the schema represent something, and that's what you'll get back.